# Apache forward vs reverse proxying

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224664/difference-between-proxy-server-and-reverse-proxy-server) question, I roughly understand what forward and reverse proxies are. However, apache can be configured as a forward or reverse proxy. I thought it would be up to the client to configure forward proxying, then why is the apache server handling forward proxying? From the perspective of the client, both forward and reverse proxying look the same.

Also, why can't I use a forward proxy to behave as a reverse proxy? They both sound conceptually the same almost. How do I decide wether to go with one or the other?

Comment: They don't fill the same functional role - a forward proxy is generally a system that a client uses to pass all of its web traffic; a reverse proxy is a system that acts as a front-end server that handles client connections and routes them to backend servers.  Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score -1):

the best solution that you going to use reverse proxies for more performance and for more security and i think that enginx that will be the best

The second partition of ur question that i think u can't do that , it's will reduce the

performance and use ur bandwith ==> This is my opinion

Regardds